# Where can I find best practices for helping people on civicrm.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Is there some sort of place where we can compile a list of commonly-used links, responses to common issues, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why yes - there's the [Community Support Documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Community+Support+Documentation) page on the CiviCRM wiki.